# Why doesn't Krename start in Ubuntu 11.10?

Tags: 11.10, kde

I have installed Krename from the official repository in Ubuntu 11.10.
But it doesn't start.

What I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

A bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/krename/+bug/849882

It has the fix/patch, workarounds, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SAMROG131 builds (as deb files) of Krename ([i386](https://launchpad.net/~samrog131/+archive/build-queue/+build/2903399/+files/krename_4.0.7-1oneiric1~bugfix~ppa1_i386.deb), [amd64](https://launchpad.net/~samrog131/+archive/build-queue/+build/2903398/+files/krename_4.0.7-1oneiric1~bugfix~ppa1_amd64.deb)).